# box/spout - Massive memory usage when using hex color vs pre-defined colors

Tags: php, phpexcel, spout

I'm using the [Box/Spout](http://opensource.box.com/spout/) library and it seems that using StyleBuilder with a custom hex color (e.g. 0000FF for blue) uses a ton of memory compared to using pre-defined colors such as Color::BLUE. Why would that be?

**Relevant snippet:**

```
//LOW MEMORY
$row[] = WriterEntityFactory::createCell('test', (new StyleBuilder())->setFontColor(Color::BLUE)->build());

//HIGH MEMORY
$row[] = WriterEntityFactory::createCell('test', (new StyleBuilder())->setFontColor($colorHex)->build());
```

**Output:**

setFontColor(Color::BLUE): `Peak memory usage: 1666 KB`

setFontColor($colorHex): `Peak memory usage: 189436 KB`

**Full code:**

(For demo purposes I'm loading a small 250x150 image to provide multiple color values)

```
<?php

    require_once 'Spout/Autoloader/autoload.php';
    use Box\Spout\Writer\Common\Creator\WriterEntityFactory;
    use Box\Spout\Common\Entity\Style\Color;
    use Box\Spout\Writer\Common\Creator\Style\StyleBuilder;

    //load an image
    $img = imagecreatefrompng('input/test250x150.png');

    $writer = WriterEntityFactory::createXLSXWriter();
    $writer->openToFile('output/MyExcel.xlsx');

    //height of the image
    for($y=0; $y<150; $y++) {

        //create or reset array to hold this row's cells
        $row = [];

        //width of the image
        for($x=0; $x<250; $x++) {

            //gets the pixel color
            $index = imagecolorat($img, $x, $y);
            $colorRGBArr = imagecolorsforindex($img, $index);
            $colorHex = sprintf("%02x%02x%02x", $colorRGBArr['red'], $colorRGBArr['green'], $colorRGBArr['blue']);

            //LOW MEMORY
            //$row[] = WriterEntityFactory::createCell('test', (new StyleBuilder())->setFontColor(Color::BLUE)->build());
            //HIGH MEMORY
            $row[] = WriterEntityFactory::createCell('test', (new StyleBuilder())->setFontColor($colorHex)->build());

        }
        $writer->addRow(WriterEntityFactory::createRow($row));
    }

    $writer->close();

    echo 'Peak memory usage: '.round(memory_get_peak_usage() / 1024).' KB';
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### tl;dr

While the `Spout` can be improved, [Excel isn't designed for large quantities of styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/clean-workbook-less-memory#formatting-considerations), so this isn't really a flaw of the library (you might want to [rescind the issue](https://github.com/box/spout/issues/721))

### The Story

Alright, there's a few things at play here.. the code I used to test is at the bottom of my post - the key relevant color functions are `jonEg` and `jonEgQuant` (which is a `$by` variable inside that can be tuned)

- Styling in Excel is a little like HTML+CSS.  Styles are defined initially in the file (in a header block) and then referenced by name (class) in the sheets.  Fundamentally this suggests the Excel storage format was not designed for a plethora of styles, but only a handful that are reused on many cells
- `Spout` hides the style-definition complexity from the user - if the style's already defined (ie. *an exact style already exists*) then it reuses that definition, otherwise a new style is defined
- `Spout` builds an index of all styles, by [serializing](https://www.php.net/serialize) the style object and storing it in an array.  At approximately 1749 bytes per style this index chews up memory (in addition to the actual style objects it has in memory to generate the file) - **this could be improved in `Spout`**
- With this code I'm guaranteeing each cell has a different style (using the row/column position to define the red and green components of the color) - *which is more extreme than your image-color-picking, but perhaps not by much* (I cannot tell without the sample image).  There are 16M colors available with an RGB triplet.. but our eyes cannot always detect a difference of a few points.  For example it'll be clear in a red gradient that 255,254,253...128 looks smooth, but a single block of 255,254,253 randomly distributed will probably look like a single color.  For anything but a primary color, this variance now applies in three dimensions (r, g, & b).  The [JPEG format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) exploits this (a combination of compression, and noise in rebuilding) - so color picking what might look like a uniform block will still return slightly different values each time
- When you run my code with `jonEg` you get (100*150+1) 15001 styles, which takes (15001*1749/1024/1024) ~25MB of memory for the index in `Spout` alone.  Again this index is needed to prevent every single cell in Excel having it's own style (but of course, in this contrived example I've made sure it's pointless - every cell does have it's own style) - this uses **~100MB** of memory
- When you run my code with `jonEgQuant` (leaving `$by=16;`) only 71 styles are needed (but this is pretty extreme rounding, allowing only 4096 colors in total), - this uses **~2MB** of memory
- When you set `$by=4` (inside `ColorBuilder::jonEgQuant`) - you now have up to quarter of a million colours, 989 styles are needed, using **~7MB** of memory (more to the point, this looks similar to `jonEg` when opened in Excel)
- `Spout` includes a method to convert RGB decimal values into a string `Color::rgb($r,$g,$b)` - but this doesn't change the outcome (`spoutDoc` method)
- A style has many more dimensions than this - I've used background colour, but there's foreground (your example), underline, bold, italic, font face, font-size - all of these multiply the style quantity (reducing the color space here addresses your documented problem, but could be undone by altering other style components)

### Take Aways

- It's not the use of hex codes, RGB values or constants that's the issue, it's the quantity of styles you're using
- Reduce the number of styles you use - Excel doesn't expect a large count, `Spout` likewise isn't optimized for this.  Compressing the color (by rounding values as with `jonEgQuant`) is one avenue
- Improve the `Spout` style index mechanism, but notice only some of the memory is consumed by the index - it's not small, but it's not the only contributor - each style object *is needed* to generate the result.  Removing this style cache (which for this contrived example doesn't help) brings memory usage to 40MB (and generates the same Excel file).  60% savings isn't nothing, but more styles makes for more memory usage, larger Excel files, and slower opening/rendering of those files

### Testing notes

- I dropped the image reading/color harvesting while testing since it may add to memory usage but not to the meat of the problem
- With `$colCount=250;` (from your example) you exceed the 128MB default memory limit in PHP, better to set it `$colCount=100;` and you can run all the tests without changing that setting
- I switched to setting background-color, it's easier to see the difference when opened in Excel
- For each color generator (`jonEg`, `spoutDoc`, `fixedEg`, `jonEgQuant`) a different XLSX is generated (helps to see the file size and rendering differences)
- The file sizes match the Excel complexity - `jonEg` is a 179KB file (and Excel struggles to open), while `jonEgQuant` is 43KB

### Code

```
<?php

require_once 'Spout/Autoloader/autoload.php';
use Box\Spout\Writer\Common\Creator\WriterEntityFactory;
use Box\Spout\Common\Entity\Style\Color;
use Box\Spout\Writer\Common\Creator\Style\StyleBuilder;

// -- -- Set this to one of the method names on ColorBuilder (that isn't a helper)
$choice='jonEg';
// -- -- 

class ColorBuilder {
    static $defaultBlue=255;
    static function jonEg($x,$y) {return sprintf("%02x%02x%02x", $x, $y, static::$defaultBlue);}
    static function spoutDoc($x,$y) {return Color::rgb($x, $y, static::$defaultBlue);}
    static function fixedEg($x,$y) {return Color::BLUE;}
    static function jonEgQuant($x,$y) {$by=16;return sprintf("%02x%02x%02x", static::_quantize($x,$by),static::_quantize($y,$by), static::_quantize(static::$defaultBlue,$by));}

    //Helpers - don't use these for choice
    static function validate(string $name):bool {
        if ($name==null) return false;//Null or empty
        if (substr($name,0,1)=='_') return false;//Private by convention
        if ($name==='validate') return false;//Not the function you seek
        return method_exists('ColorBuilder',$name);
    }
    private static function _quantize(int $i,int $by=16):int {return round($i/$by)*$by;}
}

function createRow($y,$color) {
    $colCount=100;
    $row = [];

    for($x=0; $x<$colCount; $x++) {
        $row[] = WriterEntityFactory::createCell('*', (new StyleBuilder())->setBackgroundColor(ColorBuilder::$color($x,$y))->build());
    }
    return $row;
}

function buildSheet($name) {
    if (!ColorBuilder::validate($name)) {throw new Error('Invalid color provider');}

    $writer = WriterEntityFactory::createXLSXWriter();
    $writer->openToFile('output/'.$name.'.xlsx');

    for($y=0; $y<150; $y++) {
        $writer->addRow(WriterEntityFactory::createRow(createRow($y,$name)));
    }

    $writer->close();
}

buildSheet($choice);
echo 'Peak memory usage: '.round(memory_get_peak_usage() / 1024).' KB';
```

**Tech:** `PHP 7.4.2 CLI, Spout: 3.1.0, Win: 7 x64 (I know), Coffee: Venti Dark`

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you very much, I learned a lot. You said `jonEgQuant` looks similar to `jonEg` when opened in Excel but it looks completely different at `$by=4`. I'll plug way at the `quant()` method as that's where the problem will be. Thanks again

Comment: Update. The error with the `quant()` method was that it was possible it could return a value above 255 which of course is the max for RGB (e.g. `round(254/4)*4 = 256)`. Easily fixed. Thanks

Comment: @Jon - well caught, my examples I'm only using low range numbers so it didn't matter.. but yes, it's possible to hit any number (it's a general purpose function, wrapping in `Max($quant,255)` will fix)